# how to access the Json Responce dict value in the Html script

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

My django views

```
def contact_otp(request):
        if request.method=="POST":
            data = {
        "data-token":f"{otp.token}"
    }
            #
            return JsonResponse(data)


.then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => {
            console.log(data)
            const newVarPass = document.createElement("input")
            newVarPass.setAttribute('id','varPassID')
            newVarPass.setAttribute('value',`${data}`)
            newVarPass.value=`${data}`
            newVarPass.style.display="none"
            document.body.appendChild(newVarPass)
            alert("Check your Email We have send you the otp")
            console.log(data)
            
          })

    x = document.getElementById("varPassID")
                console.log(x)
                console.log("Lets check")
```

[image]

How to get the values of the json keypair i want to have which is present in the json data i am always getting object object in the value now

updated console.log(data)

[image]

Comment: when you pass your object inside newVarPass.value=`${data}` it will treat is as a string

Comment: data={} contains a single object or there can be multiple?

Comment: It containse a single object i a updating it

Comment: @AnkitTiwari Tell me how can i achive the my wish

Comment: Hello @sarangkkl you've ``console.log(data)`` you can check which data is comming in your browser console and then access specific value from it and pass it in your input. Provide your browser console output.

Comment: @AnkitTiwari  It seems i am getting an object wait i will update it

Comment: Hello @sarangkkl now you've to access ``data.data-token`` and assign it to your input value attribute. I just noticed you're creating input element and ssigning same id to all input try to change it because id should be unique in DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("varPassID").innerText = data.data-token
```

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_innertext.asp